# sql while functions

Tags: php, sql

```
function timeago($ptime) {
    $etime = time() - $ptime;

    if ($etime < 1) {
        return '0 seconds';
    }

    $a = array( 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'year',
                    30 * 24 * 60 * 60       =>  'month',
                    24 * 60 * 60            =>  'day',
                    60 * 60                 =>  'hour',
                    60                      =>  'minute',
                    1                       =>  'second'
                    );

    foreach ($a as $secs => $str) {
        $d = $etime / $secs;
        if ($d >= 1) {
            $r = round($d);
            return $r . ' ' . $str . ($r > 1 ? 's' : '');
        }
    }
}
```

lets say i have that function, and i have an sql result that give me an array with multiple time stamps in UNIX form. using a while loop, how can i use this function for each timestamp so each loop result would contain the time ago of each sql UNIX timestamp?

Comment: Time to actually learn to program PHP.  If you knew how to write a while loop in the first place, the question answers itself. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php might also be of interest.

Comment: How does this relate to SQL at all?

Comment: Please post the query.  You can do all the work in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use DateTime class.

```
function timeAgo($ptime){
   $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat("s", $ptime);//HOPE THIS WILL WORK
   $date2 = new DateTime("now");
   $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
   $diff = $interval->format('%y-%m-%d');
   return $diff; 
}
```

invoke this method on each iteration and pass in the timestamp from the DB.